# how to have a table close to scope plot?

Tags: tables, axis, scoping

I would like to have a table near by a plot. I know how to have a table but not know having a plot near by the table. I have attached my table code and figure that I want to have.

Thanks in advance.

here my code for table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}


\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{bigstrut}


\begin{document}



    \begin{table}[th]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \centering% \scriptsize
   % \caption{Group A.}\label{group}
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{c|}}%{|*{8}{c|}}
  \cline{1-8}
%\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
%         &   
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}
                        & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{YY} \bigstrut       \\

    \cline{3-8}

\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XX} 
         &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{AA}
                  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{BB} \bigstrut                 \\
                  %&&&&&&&\\
    \hline
    A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H \bigstrut \\ \hline

    \multirow{4}{*}{}
    &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
    1&2&1&2&1&2&3&4\\
    &  &  &  &  & &  & \bigstrut  \\  \hline

     \multirow{6}{*}{}
    &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
   &  &  &  &  & &  &   \\ 
    &  &  &  &  & &  & \bigstrut  \\  \hline

\end{tabular}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

photo [image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

It is quite close to what you show in your image ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[th]
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
    \centering% \scriptsize
   \caption{Group A.}\label{group}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\bfseries]
\draw[->]   (0,0) -- ++ (0,33ex) node[above] {TY};
\draw[->]   (0,0) -- ++ (1.1,0);
\draw[very thick]  (0,0) -- (1.1,26.8ex); % 26.8ex = 2 x 11ex + 4 x cellgapes
\foreach \y in {0,13.4,26.8}
    \draw[densely dotted] (0,\y ex) node[above left,inner ysep=0pt] {2X} -- + (1.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{|*{8}{c|}}
    \cline{1-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}
    & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{YY}               \\
    \cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{XX}
         &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{AA}
                  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{BB} \\
    \hline
A   & B & C & D & E & F & G & H             \\ \hline
1   & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \rule[-5ex]{0pt}{11ex}  \\  \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \rule[-5ex]{0pt}{11ex}  \\  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```